# How to create a linked server using FluentMigrator?

Tags: transactions, linked-server, fluent-migrator

I tried to run a regular Sql script to create a linked server object in my production environment using **Execute.Sql()** method of FluentMigrator, but I get following errors from MS Sql Server:

```
The error was The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be  executed within a transaction.  
The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin' cannot be executed within a transaction.
```

Is there any way to execute the script outside the opened transaction by FluentMigrator?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also run it outside the normal transaction, by decorating the attribute like this:

```
[Migration(201604061643, TransactionBehavior.None)]
```

This is a new feature in current release, described here:
https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Transaction-modes-for-the-migration-runner

Comment: Thank you Richard, sounds it'll do the trick, but unfortunately it eliminates the transaction for the whole current executing migration. By that, you should add another migration (i.e. version) to write other DB migrations for the current release.

Comment: Ok, I see. And you ofc have to do the adding before your migratons. Maybe this is a good usecase to implement, detecting linked server creation, and handling it before transaction, and destruction after transaction.

Comment: That's a good point Richard, this way the implementation would be more robust. Thank you for your notes and for the "TransactionBehavior".

Comment: @ArmanHatefi This seems a great solution to me. Surely creating another migration to separate the creation of the Linked Server from the other (transactional) code isn't a big deal?

Comment: Dear Caltor, thank you for commenting, glad to have your points. At the first glance creating another migration might not seem a big deal, but when it comes to the migration feature which should ensure all the related stuff should be migrated together with the same migration, creating another migration might bring the chance of omitting that migration by the deployment team and also the following migration (which most likely has related stuff with this one). It also creates more than one migration which might not be feasible for production environment, software package management & rollback.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this by executing mentioned script using another SqlConnection and SqlCommand to run the mentioned scripts outside the transaction of FluentMigrator.
Any other solution will be welcomed.